# Apache http to https rewrite rule not working - but it was this afternoon

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I've got a few sites running on my apache server. I have a ssl cert on all of them. Because of this, I have a virtual host * rule that should redirect any http traffic to the related https site. If i try to go to a site right now with http, I get the apache test site... However, if I type in https, it works just fine.

Here's what my all encompassing virtual host rewrite rules look like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =api.mySiteName.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Anybody see anything that would prevent this from working?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must add the Port 443 rule.